# Does charged conductor attract uncharged insulators?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, charge

When we bring a charged conductor near uncharged insulator will it attract the insulator? Also will charged insulator also attract uncharged conductor?

Comment: Try it with a charged object and a small piece of paper.

Comment: Obviously it does, the effect is more spectacular when one of them is small as stated in the first answer. Electrostatic interactions also affect perfectly bound materials, another example are molecules (mostly insulators) attracted by interatomic electrostatic forces.